# Fetch Request with Multiple Parameters | Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

How do I send a fetch request with two parameters to my flask server? I have the flask working but I am not sure about the javascript part.

Javascript Code:

```
    var symbol = document.getElementById("stock-symbol").value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

    fetch(`/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request/${symbol}${quantity}`)
```

Python Code:

```
@app.route("/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request/<symbol>/<quantity>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def sell_stocks(symbol, quantity):
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            symbol = str(symbol)
            quantity = int(quantity)

        except ValueError:
            return render_template("sell-page.html")

        return symbol, quantity
```

Comment: Seems you have forgotten putting the `/` between `${symbol}${quantity}` in `fetch(\`/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request/${symbol}${quantity}\`)`

Comment: you can try `query` parameters like `/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request?symbol=<your symbol>&quantity=<your quantity>`, what you are using is a different route, which seems not a good design. And in flask app you can get those query parameters using `request.args`

Answer (score 0):

Using params like this:

javascript:

```js
fetch(`/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request/?symbol=${symbol}&quantity=${quantity}`)
```

python:

```py
from flask.globals import request
...
@app.route("/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request")
def sell_stocks():
    symbol = request.args.get('symbol')
    quantity= request.args.get('quantity')
    return symbol, quantity
```

**attention, params default type is string.**

If you want to continue to use this flask routings,you can do this in JavaScript

```js
fetch(`/game/market-simulator/make-sell-request/${symbol}/${quantity}`)
```

Pay attention to the sequence between **symbol** and **quantity**